# Make a Component with Promise Objects type data in React with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, javascript-objects

Below returning a Promise type Object, and an error occurred that

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   { key1, key2, key3 ...}...

How to solve this?

```
// Component.tsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Jobs() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  const request = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://api/v1/',
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            'Bearer asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf',
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setResult(data);
    return data
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rendering finished!');
    request();
  },[]);


  return (
    <div>
      <li>{result}</li>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Jobs;
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be directly rendering objects inside jsx

```
// The direct calling of result is the culprit

return (
    <div>
      <li>{result}</li>
    </div>
  );
```

You should be mapping that value instead:

```
 return (
    <div>
        <ul>{result.map(v => (
          <li>{v.title}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
     </div>
    )
```

or if you really want to console log the values of result to check. You could either console.log it outside

```
...
console.log(result)
...
return (
  <div />
);
```

or inside

```
 return (
    <div>
      <li>{console.log(result)}</li>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: At {v.title}, error occurred like `any
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Yes, because you don't have the "title" key inside your array objects of "result". it might be something else for you

Comment: It needs to be an Array to map over it as outlined above. If you've got an object you can use `Object.keys(obj).map()`